# CasperJS captureSelector not capturing correctly when zoom factor is increased

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs, screen-capture

When increasing the zoom factor(2) of a webpage and attempting to screenshot a specified class using captureSelector the image captured seems to take the screenshots from coordinates where the requested element would have been if I had not zoomed. When the zoom factor is set to 1, there is no issue and the desired class is captured. I am looking at capturing screenshots at double the native resolution for use in print media and retina enabled devices.

This is the documentation for setting the zoom factor and capturing an entire webpage. 
http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#zoom

This is the documentation for capturing an area of a webpage which contains the defined selector.
http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#captureselector

```
  var casper = require('casper').create();

  casper.start().zoom(2).thenOpen('http://weather.com', function() {
      this.captureSelector('weather.png', '#rightnow_module');
  });

  casper.run();
```

changing the zoom factor from 2 to 1 will demonstrate the difference in output. a zoom factor of 2 should output an image which is double the size, however its not working and Its got me totally stumped.

Comment: It looks like it should work now: [Make captureSelector aware of the page zoom factor. #918](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/pull/918)

Comment: I'm excited to give this a go! thanks for the update!